# Docker microsoft/nanoserver won't start

Tags: powershell, docker, cmd, hyper-v, nano-server

I have a problem with Docker running the nanoserver.

My environment: I Installed docker on a Win10 (developer build from microsoft) Virtual Machine (cause host is still Win7 with no default Docker support because of Hyper-V).  I installed docker on the virgin image so no 3rd-party programs can cause the error.  I also have already checked if Hyper-V is enabled.

But I think this Screenshot says everything:

[image: Screen shot of my error]

Also Googled the problem, but everything i found wasn't in a Docker context.

FYI: I want to use the Docker container for running a network rendering slave which should only see one cpu core (for licensing reasons), maybe someone has another option for this.

Comment: It's much easier for the community to help if you can paste your actual error messages as text into your posts, rather than paste a screen shot of a terminal window.  I see a lot of text but it's not obvious to me which thing is your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you are trying to run Docker on Windows 10 which is a VM on Windows 7? I suppose this is not possible. You are trying to run a virtualization platform inside a virtualized Host (your Windows 10 machine). This nested virtualization is not supported by Windows 7 afaik.

Nested virtualization is supported on Windows 10 Build 10565 and later (this must be your virtualization host).

Have you tried to create and run a Hyper-V VM inside that Windows 10 VM? this will also fail.

Comment: ok i already thought that this can be the error.. but i hoped it wouldn't^^